# Mapping Gatsby gallery images with GraphQL

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to figure out how to map gallery images into a lightbox component in Gatsby using graphql query. I think I need to set `images = to the childimage sharp array` but I'm not sure how to structure it, keep getting `undefined` errors. Any pointers would be massively appreciated. Let me know if any more info is required.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby"
import Image from "gatsby-image"
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';

const ComponentName = ({ data }) => {
  const {id, galleryImage} = data.home
  console.log('data is', data)
  
  const images = [];

return (
    <Layout>
    <section className="template">
    <ImageGallery items={images} />;
    </section>
    </Layout>
    
)
}

export const query = graphql`
  query GetSingleHome($slug: String) {
    home: strapiHomes(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
    galleryImage {
      formats {
        large {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
            id
          }
        }
        small {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
    MainImage {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
`

export default ComponentName
```

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery) is the gallery component in case it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, `images` `prop` should be an array of images, so applied to your use-case, `images` must be an array of object images.

Assuming that your query is working as expected and retrieving the proper data, you need to mount a valid array of objects to pass as images `prop`.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby"
import Image from "gatsby-image"
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';

const ComponentName = ({ data }) => {
  const {id, galleryImage} = data.home
  console.log('data is', data)
  
  const images = [];

  galleryImage.forEach(image=>{
    let yourImageObject={};
  
    yourImageObject.original=image.formats.large.childImageSharp.fluid;
  
    images.push(yourImageObject);
  });
  

return (
    <Layout>
    <section className="template">
    <ImageGallery items={images} />;
    </section>
    </Layout>
    )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query GetSingleHome($slug: String) {
    home: strapiHomes(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
    galleryImage {
      formats {
        large {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
            id
          }
        }
        small {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
    MainImage {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
`

export default ComponentName
```

You can simplify the code but I split to make it more readable and understandable. You need to loop through each image and create the mandatory data for the `ImageGallery` component: an array of objects with an `original` property inside with the `...GatsbyImageSharpFluid` fragment inside.

If this package won't work with Gatsby image, you may need to change a little bit as well as the GraphQL query and the code to adapt it.

I don't know the needs of that dependency but you can also add the `thumbnail` property if needed using the same approach, adding:

```
    yourImageObject.thumbnail=image.formats.small.childImageSharp.fluid;
```